# PHP album: move_uploaded_file does not work

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php and need help.

I am working with a simple album and trying to upload photos to an album folder I choose from the option but getting errors saying "No such file or directory" and "Unable to move".

I have tried changing the "$album_name" part in the path to "$row['name']" or "$album_id", but none of them worked. However, setting a fixed url works (e.g.  'uploads/bla/'.$random_name.'.jpg').

How do I include the name of the album I choose from the option in the path? Currently uploaded files are stored outside of the folders (in the "uploads" folder).

---

```
 <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>

    Select album: <br/>              
    <select name='album'>
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, name FROM albums ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $album_id = $row['id'];
      $album_name = $row['name'];
      echo "<option value=".$album_id.">".$album_name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><br/><br/>  

    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

        $album_id = $_POST['album'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $random_name = rand();

        if(empty($file)) { 
          echo "Please choose a file to upload.<br/> <br/>";
        } else {

          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.**$album_name**.'/'.$random_name.'.jpg');

          mysqli_query ($dbc, "INSERT INTO pictures VALUES('', '$album_id', '$random_name.jpg')");
          echo "Photo uploaded!!!<br/> <br/> ";
        }
      }
    ?>

   Select photo: <br/>
    <input type='file' name='file' /><br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='upload' value='Upload' />
  </form>
```

Comment: m_u_f() won't create subdirs for you. if `uploads/$album_name` doesn't already exist, then the move will fail. and note that `$rand.jpg` is **NOT** a good filename to use. rand() can/will generate the same numbers. You should be using your DB record's primary key (e.g. auto_increment int) which WILL be unique and non-duplicable.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I will try to create subdirs and use the primary key instead of rand().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of things needed to be considered when you're getting errors like that.

1. Does the directory exists? The directory "uploads" might have another name.
2. Does the directory have the correct chmod? If you're developing on Windows, then no problem. But on Linux it *is* a huge problem once the directory is 0600 and the owner is your user. In that case, either chmod the directory to 0777 (which might be a huge security risk) or change the owner to *daemon* or the user Apache (or your webserver) runs on.
3. The file size is larger than the directive in php.ini. Yes, PHP has a config file php.ini, in which the maximum uploaded file size is set. Run `find / -name php.ini` if you are on Linux to find the file. By default, the maximum filesize is 2MB.

You should also try to handle the error through `$_FILE["file"]["error"]` to see the more detailed error. The list of errors is found in the official PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: `0774` yes... `0777` not  so much

Comment: I don't get your comment. Are you implying that `chmod 0774` is a security risk and `chmod 0777` "not so much"? I'll be sorry to tell you, that `0774` would then mean others can only read, but can't write and execute and that gives no security risk. In case you suggest that the user should use `chmod 0774` on a dir to upload images, then I'll still be sorry to tell you, that if the dir belongs to user _Debian_ (as example), the user _daemon_ (which Apache uses) will not be able to upload his files, because of insufficient rights.

Comment: I'm telling u should place `0774`on dir's and `0664` on files. If your script is unable to upload from there then i'm sorry to tell U that your server is configured badly.